# OutlineTextField: Check if the text is not changed

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

I have an OutlineTextField where I am editing and updating it by calling an API on click of Save button.
Now what I want if the user doesn't change the text, api call should not happen and then onclick of save , there should not be any api call and it should got to the previous screen.
Below is my code snippet:

```
OutlinedTextField(
    value = value,
    modifier = modifier,
    onValueChange = onValueChange,
    placeholder = PlaceholderComponent
 )
```

I solved it by checking initial viewmodel text.

Comment: Just store the previous value

Comment: Glad you nailed your problem. If my answer was helpful to you, please consider accepting it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood the question clearly, as @Gabriele Mariotti suggested, you can store the previous value of the text field and then compare it with the actual in the text field itself on the button click.

You can arrange the code with a `Composable` function like so:

```
@Composable
fun SaveButton(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier
) {
    var currentValue by remember { mutableStateOf("") }
    var previousValue by remember { mutableStateOf(currentValue) }
    val context = LocalContext.current

    Row(
        verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,
        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceEvenly,
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
    ) {
        OutlinedTextField(
            value = currentValue,
            modifier = modifier,
            onValueChange = {
                currentValue = it
            }
        )

        Button(onClick = {
            if (currentValue != previousValue) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "API request started", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                previousValue = currentValue
                // Handle API request
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(context, "The text has not changed. Returning to the previous screen...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                // Handle on back screen
            }
        }) {
            Text(text = "Save")
        }
    }
}
```